# Install ssl on linux centos 6 apache 2.2 server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, installation, centos6

I have to install SSL on my server centos 6 apache 2.2 server.

First I have genetraeted CSR files as directed on below link

```
http://www.hosting.com/support/ssl/generate-a-csr-on-a-linux-server
```

and sent the generated files to my client. client has purchased ssl certificate and sent me below files.

```
mydomainname.com.crt
sf_bundle.crt
cert.pem
```

Can anyone please let me know what should be next steps where I have to upload these files ?

I have googled for if but am getting confused. I have all server permissions.

Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: There are instructions on the site where your client got the certificate: http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5238/installing-an-ssl-certificate-in-apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install mod_ssl

```
# yum install mod_ssl
```

and then modify /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
Listen 443

SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300

SSLMutex default

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.net
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

    <Directory /var/www/example.net>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/httpd/mydomainname.com.crt
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/httpd/sf_bundle.crt
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/httpd/cert.pem

    <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Files>
    <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

    CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: If the key is not combined with the certificate, you must specify SSLCertificateKeyFile directive to point at the key file.

You can get more info at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html